# Node Cluster and/or Docker Cluster?

Tags: node.js, docker, load-balancing, node-cluster

Trying to get the best performance from my application with as little setup as possible.

I'm struggling to find a consensus online of whether it would be better to use the Node `cluster` module in a Docker container, or to use a cluster of Docker instances instead.

[OPINION: Node cluster first, then Docker cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547993/docker-containers-and-node-js-clusters)

[OPINION: Don't use Node cluster in a Docker instance](https://medium.com/@CodeAndBiscuits/understanding-nodejs-clustering-in-docker-land-64ce2306afef#.9x6j3b8vw)

Answer (score 2):

Depends what "best performance" means? What is the bottleneck in your case? CPU? RAM? Network? Disk-I/O?
Advantages of a node cluster:

- All communication is in memory.

Disadvantage

- The solution doesn't scale beyond one host. If the host is overloaded, then so is your service

Advantages of a docker cluster:

- high availability.
- more network bandwidth, more resources as you have more hosts

Assuming you run your software as a service in docker anyway, I can't see the issue of "little setup as possible". Use both if it makes sense.

Comment: Network is the bottleneck in my case.

Do I have more network availability if my machine has 4 cores and I run 4 docker instances or 1 docker instance and a node cluster utilizing all 4 cores?

Do I potentially lose performance by not using the ```cluster``` module?

Comment: if you have 1 host it just doesn't matter what you choose. I would pack my software in docker containers anyways for the whole build chain. Really depends now if you want rolling updates (=> docker cluster) or only have one system (=> nodejs cluster).